# WSL/explorer.exe not functional

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run the Debian distro under WSL. I used to run Ubuntu, then switched. I used to be able to run "explorer.exe [filename]" and have windows open the file. This no longer works. Commands such as cmd.exe or notepad.exe also do not work, only yeilding a message similar to:

`-bash: explorer.exe: command not found`

any help is much appreciated

thanks

edit: 
debian version 9.7, Windows 10 Version  10.0.17763 Build 17763.

My apologies.

to be more clear, I would like to be able to open files (specifically pdf files) from the Debian bash shell as if I had double clicked on them in file explorer. This previously worked, and has since stopped. Is there any way to do this in WSL?

thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are attempting to use.  Please indicate which Debian distribution you are using (the version).  Please indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.  Provide all of this information in an edit to your question instead of a comment

Comment: Try researching the “command not found” error message.

Comment: Hey @Scott, I found that "command not found WSL" was too broad of a search for me, and did not have enough information on the subject. I hoped that someone here might be able to point me in the right direction. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound is that better? I'd simply like to be able to open files (really just launch PDFs in edge) from the WSL Debian bash shell. Thanks